# Compare slopes between two groups of equal size

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, group-differences, ancova

I want to compare how does a dependent variable (total flow) changes with a covariate (total rain) between two groups (stream A & B). Usually, i would go with ANCOVA. But these groups have the same number of observations. And each observation in A correspond to an observation in B, because they were generated from the same rain event (total rain).  Do i:

1. Do an ANCOVA/multiple-regression
2. Find the difference between A and B, then regress those values against the covariate?

If method 2 is better, i have tried and got some negative values from A-B. How do i go about it?

I hosted the sample data [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=20162206528062288434&t=2016220652806228843413022)

Thank you...